# How to exit loop correctly?

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, common-lisp

I want to give user three options in my cli program to choose from and have this "menu" open until he enters "e" for exit. This is my solution:

```
 (format t "~%(E)xit program - (M)ore details - enter (C)ustom data~%")
 (loop
   (setq what-to-do-next (read-char))
   (cond ((char-equal what-to-do-next #\m)
          (format t "more details~%"))
         ((char-equal what-to-do-next #\c)
          (format t "custom data~%"))
         ((char-equal what-to-do-next #\e)
          ()))
   (when (char-equal what-to-do-next #\e)
     (return nil)))
```

This works, however when program ends I get double "terminal handle" as seen in the output below:

```
(E)xit program - (M)ore details - enter (C)ustom calendar
e
[user@host ~]$ 
[user@host ~]$
```

What am I missing and how to avoid having this double return?

I tried to add variable setter to the last condition which will be exit condition for loop but I had same results.

```
 (format t "~%(E)xit program - (M)ore details - enter (C)ustom data~%")
 (setq exit 0)
 (loop
   (setq what-to-do-next (read-char))
   (cond ((char-equal what-to-do-next #\m)
          (format t "more details~%"))
         ((char-equal what-to-do-next #\c)
          (format t "custom data~%"))
         ((char-equal what-to-do-next #\e)
          (setq exit 1)))
   (when (= exit 1)
     (return nil)))
```

Comment: I try it on a Lisp REPL and it works correctly. I see only one "CL-USER" on exit. Did you build an executable to run this on the terminal? We'll need to see the surrounding code.

Comment: BTW your `setq what-do-to-next …` sets an undefined variable, we get a compilation warning. Either you declared it earlier on, either you should. For example: `(loop for what-to-do-next = (read-char) do ….`

Comment: This is highly platform and implementation-dependent and there is not nearly enough information here for this to be an answer, but what is probably happening is that you typed `e` followed by a newline.  The newline was never read by whatever Lisp you are using, but was left to be read by the shell once Lisp had exited.  To provide any kind of reasonable answer you would need to specify both the Lisp implementation, more of the program (which is horribly illegal CL as it stands) and the platform it's running on.

Comment: regarding more infrormation:
I am running CLISP 2.49.93+ (2018-02-18) on Gnu/linux fedora 37, Xfce terminal emulator. This what I gave you is full code I run, nothing else - I firstly run code on separate file.lisp and then test it in my final code. And also, I do not use REPL, but write code into file which I run with clisp file.lisp

Comment: regarding mr. ignis volens - which parts are horribly illegal? I am new to common lisp and this is only my second program I am working on. If you could help me with "illegal" syntax or formating I would be very happy to give you my contact.